# Create a method instance with a parameter

Tags: c#, .net

How can I call the parameter which is inside the method instance in the other class, as I want to make a calculation with the method and display it.

```
class Box
{
    int width = 10;
    int height = 15;

    public int Area(int Area)
    {
        Area = width * height;

        return Area;
    }

    public int Perimeter(int Para)
    {
        Para = 2 * (height + width);

        return Para;
    }
}
```

\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Box b = new Box();
     b.Area(Area);
     b.Perimeter(Para);

     Console.ReadLine();
 }
```

It is giving me en error on b.Area(Area); and b.Perimeter(Para);

Comment: `It is giving me en error` what error?

Comment: It looks like `Area` and `Perimeter` don't need parameters at all and you can change them to e.g. `public int Area() { return width * height; }`

Comment: @Reniuz "The name 'Area' does not exist in the current contest" the same with 'Para'

Comment: You have to define them first and in the `main()` - they are not. Please, next time post code that compiles.

Comment: Solved it, thanks for the advise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you wanted to do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Box box = new Box(10, 15);
        Console.WriteLine("Area is: " + box.CalculateArea());
        Console.WriteLine("Perimeter is: " + box.CalculatePerimeter());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Box
{
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public Box(int width, int height)
    {
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
    }

    public int CalculateArea()
    {
        return Width * Height;
    }

    public int CalculatePerimeter()
    {
        return 2 * (Width + Height);
    }
}
```